# JQuery function to find state of a node in jstree?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing difficulty retrieving the state of a selected node in jstree(using JSON data). Here is how I am trying to implement things:

```
$(function () {
    $("#tree").jstree({ 
        "json_data" : {
            "data" : [
                { 
                    data : "/", 
                    attr : { "id" : "root"},
                    state : "closed",
                    "children" : [ { "data" : "child1",
                                    "attr" : { "id" : "child1.id" },
                                    "children" : [ ] }
                                 ]
                },
            ]
        },
        "plugins" : [ "themes", "json_data", "crrm", "ui" ]
    })
    .bind("select_node.jstree",function(event, data) { . . . }
```

According to my research I found that `data.rslt.obj.attr("state")` should return the `state("open" or "closed")` but it returns undefined. Can you help me identify what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, jsTree does not store the state anywhere (especially after consulting the source code), but uses the node's class in order to determine it.

Therefore, my best suggestion would be to do something like:

```
(...)
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var isOpen = data.rslt.obj.hasClass("jstree-open");
    console.log(data, 'selection is ' + (isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! Can you help me know how can I delete just child and sub-child nodes of a selected node and not the selected node itself for the same code as above ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated by `@digringo`

```
$('#tree').jstree(true).get_state()
```

This returns an object that includes an array of `<li>` id that are opened and an array of `<li>` id that are selected.

You can then iterate through the array to see if the particular child is open and/or selected.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('#tree').jstree(true).get_state()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.